# Propagate Reference dependencies between projects

Tags: silverlight, dll, reference, dependencies, propagation

here the situation: I work under VS2013, I have a Silverlight solution named "MySolution" and in that solution I have a certain number of projects.

- MySolution

  - Commons
  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3
  - ...

Each project has into its References the Commons.dll file.
I want to add a new Reference in the Commons project, i.e. NewFile.dll (Commons -> Add new Reference -> NewFile.dll).
If I compile, everything is ok: into each xap I see Commons.dll increased by the size of NewFile.dll's. If I try to execute the xaps remotely by the browser I have an error: Impossible to load file of Assembly NewFile.dll. How can I manage this? Where I am wrong?

Comment: I suppose that my problem is related to the option "Reduce XAP size by using application library caching". I tried to apply the .extmap.xml to Commons project and it works in that way: VS2013 does not generate Commons.zip but automatically include each dll into each xap...